# Reloading page with a query string upon login for admins

Tags: login, actions, authentication

After users with specific roles log in, I would like to reload the current page with a query string added (to trigger a message via JavaScript).

How can this be improved?

```
function show_hi_admin_message() {
  global $current_user;

  get_currentuserinfo();

  if ( user_can( $current_user, 'administrator' ) ) {
    ?>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        window.location.replace(window.location.href.split('#')[0] + '?message=hiadmin');
    });
    </script>
    <?php
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_login', 'show_hi_admin_message' );
```

Comment: Javascript redirects like this are not ideal.  Why wouldn't you just use PHP to output a javascript variable that will trigger the message, rather than trying to do a reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the filter hook:

```
function user1462_login_redirect( $redirect_to, $request, $user ) {
    global $user;

    if ( isset( $user->roles ) && is_array( $user->roles ) ) {

        if ( in_array( 'administrator', $user->roles ) ) {
            return $redirect_to . '?message=hiadmin';
        } else {
            return home_url();
        }
    } else {
        return $redirect_to;
    }
}
add_filter( 'login_redirect', 'user1462_login_redirect', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: I'm using a custom login form, so this code doesn't execute unless I log in via WP Admin. Any idea how to hook it into a custom login form?

Comment: Add a custom filter hook? Without see the custom form, it's hard to know.

Comment: Why is $user passed as a parameter **and** declared global? (I've been staring at the example at https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/login_redirect which has the same idiom.)